# PowerBI Complex Calculated Column with multiple TOPN loops

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

Using the information below I need to create a new table in DAX called Table.

My problem is that the below measure for the "new value" column is only returning the TOPN audit record for the saleID (as long as the audit record can contain the sale date between the "changed date" and "valid until" date.). This filter should be adjusted to only detect whether the "changed Date" occurred on or after the "Sale Date". The "Valid Until" column shouldn't factor into this calculation.

```
new value = 
VAR CurrentContractDate = [Sale Date]
RETURN
VAR RespEmp =
            TOPN (
                1,
                DynamicsAudit,
                IF (
                    CurrentContractDate <= DynamicsAudit[Valid Until]
                        && CurrentContractDate >= DynamicsAudit[Changed Date], //Check, whether there is matching date
                    DATEDIFF ( DynamicsAudit[Changed Date], DynamicsAudit[Valid Until], DAY ), //If so, rank matching locations (you may want to employ a different formula)
                    MIN (  //If the location is not matching, calculate how close it is (from both start and end date)
                        ABS ( DATEDIFF ( CurrentContractDate, DynamicsAudit[Changed Date], DAY ) ),
                        ABS ( DATEDIFF ( CurrentContractDate, DynamicsAudit[Valid Until], DAY ) )
                    ) + 1000000 //Add a discriminating factor in case there are matching rows that should be favoured over non-matching.
                ), 1
            )
            RETURN
            SELECTCOLUMNS( RespEmp,"ResponsibleEmployee", [new value] )
```

So what does such a complex filter look like?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Can you phrase it in one sentence? If you want to solve a complex production problem, find time to divide it into several problems which might be stated in one sentence. It would be fantastic if you could trouble even more to provide handcrafted sample data, and not just copy-paste your production environment. If you recreate your production problem with simple data, you got a 90% chance that you will solve it yourself. If you do not want to bother to craft education question that might serve others then there are a handful of freelancer platforms.

Comment: The very first sentence provides you with the handcrafted sample data you are asking for.  The question is in one sentence, indicated directly below the sample code. Everything you asked for is already there.

Comment: What you're trying to do is very hard using DAX, is there no way you can prepare the data model differently? For example, combine Employee and Contact?

Comment: Not really. The two tables come from different databases and actually use a relational table because it is a multiple to multiple relationship...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new value = 
VAR sale = [SaleID]
VAR saleDate = [Sale Date]
VAR tbl = SUMMARIZE(FILTER(DynamicsAudit, DynamicsAudit[SaleID] = sale && DynamicsAudit[Changed Date] >= saleDate),DynamicsAudit[new value])
VAR tbl2 = NATURALINNERJOIN(
            FILTER(DbEmployees, DbEmployees[StartDate]<=saleDate && DbEmployees[EndDate] >= saleDate),
            CALCULATETABLE(DynamicsContacts, TREATAS(tbl, DynamicsContacts[EmployeeID])))

RETURN MAXX(TOPN(1,tbl2, IF(DbEmployees[Position] = "clerk", 1,2), ASC), DynamicsContacts[EmployeeID])
```

First table expression gets you the list of employees that qualify.

Second table expression joins the Employee (filtered by the ones that had a contract active during the sale date) and Contacts (filtered by the ones that qualify)

Finally do a Top 1 where it picks first the Clerks and then the Managers.